# Expressing exclusive dependency in karaf

Tags: apache-karaf

Is there a way to express an exclusive feature dependency in karaf, i.e. suppose there are two features A and B, both of which provide services amongst which is one with an interface X but whose implementation bundle is different between A and B. 
When starting feature B, would it be possible to express in karaf that feature A needs to be unloaded, or otherwise warn the user that two services with the same interface are now active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those kind of dependencies have to be solved on std. OSGi Service level. For example you might want to introduce some extra flag for the service provided by feature B and select this service with a filter while referencing it.